# double numeric control formatting

Tags: wpf, mvvm

If anyone can think of a better description for this question please let me know, I know it's terrible.

I have a numeric control which consists of a slider, textbox, and a numeric touchpad.

The number displayed in the textbox is editable, and always displays to its precision.  1.0, 2.0 etc.

The problem is, I press backspace next to the decimal on 1.0, the number changes to 10.0 (as it's just deleted the decimal) this makes sense, however I'd like instead, to somehow make backspace skip over the decimal.  Is anyone aware of any way this can be done?

--edit--

currently the value displayed in the textbox is formatted using the following

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour RegularExpression="^\-?\d+\.?\d*$"
                                                             MaxLength="9"
                                                             EmptyValue="0.0" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And in the code behind it's updated with

```
    public double SliderValue
    {
        get { return _sliderValue; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty( ref _sliderValue, Truncate( value ) );
            TextBoxValue = _sliderValue.ToString( "F" + Precision );
        }
    }

    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get
        {
            _textBoxValue = SliderValue.ToString( "F" + Precision );
            return _textBoxValue;
        }
        set
        {
            //not important
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way around the issue.  Captured the backspace button press in the form.

This checks whether the caret is next to the decimal using the following.

```
        var precision = DataContext.GetType().GetProperty("Precision").GetValue(DataContext, null);
        var p = Convert.ToInt32(precision);
        if ( ValueDisplayBox.CaretIndex == ValueDisplayBox.Text.Length - p )
        {
            ValueDisplayBox.CaretIndex--;
        }
```

I may need to add e.handled depending on how they want to handle this, but it seems to do what I need it to.